# Difference between prototype-based constructor function and ES6 class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

I'm trying to understand the difference between the 3 following functions. I came up with a few "conclusions" after a day on MDN and other sources and I was wondering if anybody could help me validate them. Thank you :)

#### BLOCK #1 (prototype-based constructor function example)

```
function Person (name){
    this.name = name;
    this.greeting = function(){
      alert(this.name);
      };
    }
  var person = new Person('Bob');
```

#### BLOCK #2 (another prototype-based constructor function example)

```
function Person(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    Person.prototype.greeting = function() {
      alert(this.name);
    }
  let person = new Person("Bob");
```

#### BLOCK #3 (prototype-based ES6 class example)

```
 class Person {
   constructor(name) {
     this.name = name;
   }
   greeting() {
     alert(this.name);
   }
 }
 let person = new Person("Bob");
```

Questions:

1. The three functions add the name and greeting members to the Person object prototype. Is this statement correct?
2. Code in Block #3 uses the new ES6 class keyword and works "behind the scenes" in a different way compared to the code in Block #1 and Block #2. (PS. I'm writing "behind the scenes" because I don't have yet a clear view of what happens under the hood when I call the function, but for the time being I assume I am too new to deep dive).
3. Code in Block #1 and  Block #2 reach the same and work "behind the scenes" in the same way. The difference in the code between the two is that in Block #1 we keep both the `name` variable and the function `greeting` in the same block of code, while in Block #2 we keep the function `greeting` separate from the variable `name` (adding the `greeting` function to the Person prototype, using `Person.prototype.greeting`)
4. Using `Person.prototype.greeting = function () {...}` in Block #2, we achieve the same result as putting `this.greeting = function (...)` below `this.name` in Block #1

Thank you!

Comment: What's the difference between block #1 and block #3? I can't spot the difference besides a different class name and the fact that you don't invoke the method

Comment: "*Using `Person.prototype.greeting = function () {...}`, we achieve the same result as putting `this.greeting = function (...)` below `this.name`*" - [**no**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

Comment: Sorry, I had copy pasted the wrong code. Now it has been fixed @CristianTraìna

Comment: You know #3 is still prototype “based” right?

Comment: yes @evolutionxbox, you are right. I edited the text for future readers

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions:

1. No, the statement is not correct, neither code adds the "name" to the prototype and only code blocks #2 and #3 add the greeting to the prototype.
2. It probably is too deep of a dive, I cannot verify what precisely happens behind the scenes, but the code essentially behaves as block #2.
3. Code blocks #1 and #2 definitively do not work the same way, nor do they reach the same end results. The block one (and i have to remind you, as written by me, since I am operating under the assumption you made a mistake in copy-paste) will create an instance of an object and assign both the property **name** and function **greeting** to the newly created instance, whereas code block #2 will assign the property **name** to the instance, but the function **greeting** to the prototype, so the other half of your question #3 is correct.
4. Absolutely not, for every object created using block #1, you are defining and creating a new instance of the function **greeting** and attaching it to the newly created object, you are not using prototype inheritance at all in this case.

Comment: You are right @Dellirium, I had made a mistake in copy-pasting. I edited the code and replaced it with the correct one (which is also reflecting the code you wrote).

Comment: Okay then all my points stand since the assumption of a mistake was correct, i will edit the answer to remove the "assumption part" and avoid confusion for future readers. The 4 answers given bellow are valid.